# Conditional probability: If $P(A\mid\bar B)=x$ then what is $P(A\mid B)$?

Tags: probability

If $P(A|\bar B)=x$, then what will be $P(A|B)$=? or vice versa. Assume $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are known. Is there some probability rule or property that I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)-P(A\cap\bar B)=P(A)-P(A\mid\bar B)P(\bar B),
$$
hence
$$
P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)-P(A\mid\bar B)(1-P(B))}{P(B)}$$
Of course, $P(A\mid\bar B)$ alone does not determine $P(A\mid B)$, but $P(A\mid\bar B)$ plus $P(A)$ plus $P(B)$ do.

Comment: thanks @Did, this was helpful derivation